Could someone assist on why my Office script isnt deleting my completed task on Excel Online?
SO i have two sheets on my online excel. One is for the team to write their task and the other is for the archived completed tasks. My script was originally working until i popped it into power automate and then it stop due to it not having any complete tasks to move over. Then my script got an error "Line 14: Range getResizedRange: Parameter out of range". So i popped in the if statement in line if(get_visible_view.getRowCount()> 0) on line 10 down to 17. But now it no longer copy and paste my completed task to the other sheet nor does it delete from the original sheet its pulling the date from. My end goal is to have a scrip that will work with my scheduled flow to move over completed task to the completed sheet.
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let table = workbook.getTable("Table");

    // Apply checked items filter on table table column Status
    table.getColumnByName("Status").getFilter().applyValuesFilter(["COMPLETE"]);
    let COMPLETE_ARCHIVE = workbook.getWorksheet("COMPLETE ARCHIVE");
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    let get_visible_view = table.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getVisibleView();
    
    if(get_visible_view.getRowCount()> 0){
        let paste = COMPLETE_ARCHIVE.getRange("A1").getRangeEdge(ExcelScript.
            KeyboardDirection.down).getOffsetRange(1, 0);
        // paste done tasks
        let paste_loc = paste.getResizedRange(get_visible_view.getRowCount()-1,
            get_visible_view.getColumnCount()-1);
        paste_loc.setValue(get_visible_view.getValues());
    }

        // Clear filter on table table column "Status"
    table.getColumnByName("Status").getFilter().clear();

        // delete completed tasks
    let table_rows = table.getRowCount();
    let table_range = table.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getValues();
    
    // loop. office 0 based. working bottom to top
    for (var i = table_rows -1; i >-1; i--) {
        if (table_range[i][7].toString().toUpperCase() == "COMPLETE") {
            table.deleteRowsAt(i,1);
        }
    }
}


What's the output if you run the script w/o PA on online Excel App or local installed Excel 365?
